# Running Hello World using Node js Express in cloud 9IDE

Tags: node.js, express, cloud9-ide

I successfully ran hello world in cloud 9 IDE using node JS express framework by replacing

```
app.listen(3000);
```

to

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

cloud 9 is asking me to use process.env.IP as the host for the scripts. Which file do I open to replace the host name to process.env.IP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `listen` with an additional parameter like this:

```
app.listen(3000, '192.168.0.100');
```

or,

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

So this should be what you are looking for. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/express-js/akZIjyp8N1g/lD80RCVLCFwJ good explanation there

Comment: Thanks. Got it working. I updated to express 3.1.0 and it ran out of the box