# Can't get Node.js Express code to say 'Hello World' in Cloud 9

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cloud9-ide, cloud9

Been experimenting with Cloud 9 and have been trying to use the example code from the [Express website](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) in order to get 'Hello World!'.  I tried listening to several different ports/ip referring to https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application and [Running Hello World using Node js Express in cloud 9IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087953/running-hello-world-using-node-js-express-in-cloud-9ide).  Although the listener will run, it will never close or return anything after that.  Does anyone know why this may be?  Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log('LISTENING');
});
```

Comment: What do you see when you go to your localhost:port in the browser?

Comment: 'Cannot GET /'  So then it must be the path argument.  Is there a universal path argument used for Cloud 9 when testing?

Comment: there is a 'preview' button on taskbar on left side of 'run' button. Just click that you should see what url you need to hit and hello world will also show up. I just tried your code and it works,

Comment: @Sikorski Last night I tried that several times with no luck, but this morning it is actually FINALLY showing me 'Hello World!'.  Now, my question is why doesn't it show that in the command line?  Shouldn't it show that?  Shouldn't it close the connection at some point, also?  It just doesn't want to stop listening.

Comment: It's weird, but I think I understand it now.  It only shows the get request when I preview the application.  I threw a console.log() inside of there just to see what would happen.  The console.log() finally appeared when I opened the application, otherwise it was only listening until I did that.  It doesn't seem to want to close in command line, but maybe it's not supposed to?  Is it supposed to keep listening until I ctrl+C every time?

Comment: yes it will keep on listening until you kill the process. Good work on finally figuring it out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the `app.js` from the c9 command, which is just below, in the editor.
Cloud9 has it's own default path to run. Default like something :

https://helloexpress-abcd.c9.io/

`helloexpress` is the project name you defined, in your case it's different,

> *abcd* is the username and the *rest are the defaults*

This should show **Hello World**